# How to make constant and variable mix query for nodejs and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am in bit of situation where i have to make field name dynamic consisting of variable and some constant. I do know how to use just variable to make field name.

```
var index = parseInt(req.body.index);
db.collection("user_data").update(
 { "user_id": user_id }, 
 { $addToSet: { "share.index.comment": usr_data } }, 
 function (err, result) {
```

as here in field space i want to use index variable with constant share and comment

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this:

```
var index = parseInt(req.body.index);
var commentData = { };
commentData["share." + index + ".comment"] = usr_data;

db.collection("user_data").update(
  { "user_id": user_id }, 
  { "$addToSet": commentData }, 
  function (err, result) {

  }
)
```

In that way the value of "index" is acutally used for the "dot notation" string required in the statement.